# How to convert text file with two columns to fasta format

Tags: python

I am kind of confused with this bit of code. I have my `testfile.txt`

```
Sclsc1_3349_SS1G_09805T0        TTGCGATCTATGCCGACGTTCCA
Sclsc1_8695_SS1G_14118T0        ATGGTTTCGGC
Sclsc1_12154_SS1G_05183T0       ATGGTTTCGGC
Sclsc1_317_SS1G_00317T0         ATGGTTTCGGC
Sclsc1_10094_SS1G_03122T0       ATGGTTTCGGC
```

I want to convert this file to this format (`fasta`) below:

```
>Sclsc1_3349_SS1G_09805T0
TTGCGATCTATGCCGACGTTCCA
>Sclsc1_8695_SS1G_14118T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_12154_SS1G_05183T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_317_SS1G_00317T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_10094_SS1G_03122T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
```

Here is my python code (run it like: `python mycode.py testfile.txt outputfile.txt`, but it does not output the result as I wanted. Can someone please help me correct this code? Thanks!

```
import sys

#File input
fileInput = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

#File output
fileOutput = open(sys.argv[2], "w")

#Seq count
count = 1 ;

#Loop through each line in the input file
print "Converting to FASTA..."
for strLine in fileInput:

    #Strip the endline character from each input line
    strLine = strLine.rstrip("\n")

    #Output the header
    fileOutput.write("> " + str(count) + "\n")
    fileOutput.write(strLine + "\n")

    count = count + 1
print ("Done.")

#Close the input and output file
fileInput.close()
fileOutput.close()
```

Comment: are you on Linux?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes

Comment: how about short command-line one-liner?

Comment: I could try  one liner, but I would also like to use this code.

Comment: You need to `split()` your rows if you want to extract the two components. `name, seq = strLine.split()`.

Comment: @JulienD Could you please add this as your answer?

Comment: I wrote you the code in my comment, all you have to do is try it. But I prefer the awk answer in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are on Linux OS, here is short and fast ***awk*** one-liner:

```
awk '{ printf ">%s\n%s\n",$1,$2 }' testfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

---

The `outputfile.txt` contents:

```
>Sclsc1_3349_SS1G_09805T0
TTGCGATCTATGCCGACGTTCCA
>Sclsc1_8695_SS1G_14118T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_12154_SS1G_05183T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_317_SS1G_00317T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
>Sclsc1_10094_SS1G_03122T0
ATGGTTTCGGC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
inp = open('Dataset.csv', "r")
outp = open('Book1.txt', "w")


print ("Convertion")
for a in inp:
    a = a.rstrip("\n")

    outp.write("> " + strLine[0:6] + "\n")
    outp.write(strLine[11:-4] + "\n")



print ("Done")

inp.close()
outp.close()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!